# Nginx + Wordpress + Permalinks | Strange behavior from server block

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, permalinks

It's been two days I'm trying every possible configurations. I'm getting half-way there, but never all the way.

It's done on a remote server with fresh Debian 9.14 install after my HDD died.
MariaDB + php7.0-fpm + nginx 1.10.3

I can access the Homepage & Wp-admin, but all others pages are 404 when in custom permalinks. I can access everything when permalinks are in Plain.

I have several websites, same issue for all.

My folder structure is : /var/www/website1/ && /var/www/website2/  etc...

Here are my nginx config:

> /etc/nginx/site-available/default

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name xx.xxx.xx.xxx;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

**NOTE: from there, I apparently don't need to setup any other config file for the other website... I can access them all just with that. Is this normal? On my previous server, I had to create per site config files.**

Still, here is one of them

> /etc/nginx/site-available/website1

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name _;

    root /var/www/website1;
    charset utf-8;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html { root /usr/share/nginx/html; }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/website-access.log combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/website-error.log error;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
       # Don't use `$uri` here, see https://github.com/yandex/gixy/issues/77
        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$request_uri/ permanent;
        rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
        rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) $2 last;
    }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
                allow all;
        }

        location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        }

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
            #try_files $uri $uri/ /website1/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            #satisfy any;
            #allow all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

But as I say, with or without that file, I can access website1. The fact that I can access it (or any other website in /var/www/) just with the default config file seems weird to me... Still the permalink issue remains.

> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        #tcp_nopush on;
        #tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        # Upstream to abstract backend connection(s) for PHP.
        upstream php {
                #this should match value of "listen" directive in php-fpm pool
                server unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
                #server 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I'm not an nginx expert and always had a hard time with its configuration, but always figured it out. But here I feel really stuck.
Thanks for your help!

---

### UPDATE

I managed to get the permalinks to work on website1, but now I can't figure out how to add other hosts.

Here is the new file. It's also the only config file used. No /etc/nginx/site-available/website1 is used...

> /etc/nginx/site-available/default

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

          listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
          listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
                ssl on;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx.key;
                ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx.pem;
                ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-$
                ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


        root /var/www/website1;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$args;
        }

rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
        }


location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }

    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}


        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found something that works. Please tell me if it's correct to best practices, if not, how should I do it?

Here the config that works, I only use one file to declare all sites...

> /etc/nginx/site-available/default

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    root /var/www;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  xx.xxx.xx.xxx;

    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location ~ \.php$ {
    include         snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location /website1 {
        root /var/www;
        try_files $uri /website1 /index.php?$args;
        }

     location /website2{
        root /var/www;
        try_files $uri /website2/index.php?$args;
        }

     location /website3{
        root /var/www;
        try_files $uri /website3/index.php?$args;
        }    
}
```

Comment: If 3 websites with different domain names then I would consider 3 additional vhost files for each of the websites. Then in each vhost use the server_name directive e.g `  server {
            listen *:80;

           server_name website1.com;
           root /var/www/website1/;

           location / {
           
           }
}`

Comment: As opposed to putting everything in one file, which can lead to that one file growing into one big file.  You may also need/want to add website specific options in each file.

Comment: @mrjamesmyers Thanks for your reply. I actually don't have domain names as it's a test server, I'm just running the websites on http://ip_adress_/website1 & http://ip_adress_/website2 etc. In that case, is it still possible to separate each site in its own vhost file? When I try, then the permalinks do not work anymore...